# How to debug NetworkManager shared connections

Tags: networking, systemd, dnsmasq, networkmanager

On a ubuntu 18.04 PC, I have two wifi cards, and one NetworkManager connection to each card. The two NetworkConnections are:

1. A connection named Up - This is the upstream connection, i.e. it is connected to the internet via a wireless router (the router has ip addresses 192.168.1.0/24)
2. A connection named Gate - This connection running in ap mode, shares the internet connection obtained via Up to other devices connected to Gate (the `ipv4.addresses` is set to `192.168.2.0/24`, and the PC itself has IP 192.168.2.3 )

On the PC itself, I have no problem browsing the internet, but on another device connected to Gate, I cannot access the internet, any idea what might went wrong?

Here are the connection file of the Gate network

```
[connection]
id=Gate
uuid=some uuid
type=wifi
autoconnect-priority=90
interface-name=wlo1
permissions=

[wifi]
# 2.4GHz
band=bg
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=ap
# disable power saving
powersave=2
ssid=Gate

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=some-password

[ipv4]
address1=192.168.2.3/24
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I didn't have `ifupdown` installed.